# Aligning TextViews in RelativeLayout in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I am using a RelativeLayout in a FrameLayout, but I can't seem to get the alignment right. Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

[image]

And here is my current XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgDealImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/dealImage" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtDealDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#80999999" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtSupporters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtDealDesc"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#e6e600"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtRegularPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtSupporters"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtSupporters"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#888"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtDealPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/txtRegularPrice"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtRegularPrice"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#01a05f" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT: ANSWER**

I played around with it a little bit and found out that it was my ImageView that was set to `wrap_content` which should have been `fill_parent`. Thanks for all your input guys!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imgDealImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtDealDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#80999999"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtSupporters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#e6e600"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:text="2" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtRegularPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#888"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:text="3" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtDealPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#01a05f"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:text="4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. Please note this XML is for a dynamic ListView row that I reuse multiple times. So the code above, just puts the first TextView on top-left. The other two TextViews appear below that, but it is only on the next line. It doesn't align it to the bottom of the image. I don't need the `android:text="x"` because I add that in dynamically.

Comment: Dear @Rock - We are not here to write a code or design for your requirement,First Understand that. We May try to help you then you need to try so Try it yourself. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="223dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <TextView android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I am trying to stick to a FrameLayout.